# perl eval to get single element array

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to figure out how to use perl's eval to get a single element array.  So far, I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub printit
{
    my $param = shift;
    my $thing = eval $param;
    if (ref($thing) =~ /HASH/ || ref($thing) =~ /ARRAY/) {
        print Dumper \$thing;
    } else {
        print $param . "\n";
    }
}
my $ip = "192.168.1.100";
my $ip_array = "[192.168.1.100]";
my $ip_array2 = "[192.168.1.100,]";
my $string = "{ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3}";
my $another_string = "[1, 2, 3 ]";

printit($ip);
printit($string);
printit($another_string);
printit($ip_array);
printit($ip_array2);
```

My output looks like:

```
[user]$ perl ~/tmp/cast.pl 
192.168.1.100
$VAR1 = \{
            'c' => 3,
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
          };
$VAR1 = \[
            1,
            2,
            3
          ];
$VAR1 = \[
            "\x{c0}\x{a8}d"
          ];
$VAR1 = \[
            "\x{c0}\x{a8}d"
          ];
```

I think I'm getting a scalar ref for the last 2 print outs but I want an array with a single element like this:

```
$VAR1 = \[
            "192.168.1.100"
          ];
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're getting? I've just tried running your code, and got the desired output...

Comment: @Sobrique: What Perl version do you run?

Comment: Activeperl 5.20.1 - guessing we might have a quote interpolation thing going on here. Does: `my $ip_array = "['192.168.1.100']";` show the same problems?

Comment: `print Dumper \$thing;` should be `print Dumper $thing;`. Use `\ ` when you want to dump a variable that's not a scalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval "[192.168.1.100]"` is an array reference, not a scalar reference. The array reference contains one element, but it is not the string `"192.168.1.100"` as you might expect, because `192.168.1.100` is not quoted. Instead you are creating the [*version string*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings) `192.168.1.100`.

The fix is to include a quote or quoting operator in your input.

```
my $ip_array = "['192.168.1.100']";
my $ip_array2 = "[qq/192.168.1.100/,]";
```

See "Version Strings" in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings).

Comment: Thanks @choroba for the edit -- I was having trouble finding the docs

Comment: Do you know if that's version specific? Because as noted - the OPs code works ok on my `5.20.2` perl. (Although granted, probably has other unintended consequences due to data typing)

Comment: @Sobrique, Look again. You are getting `[ 192.168.1.100 ]` instead of the desired `[ "192.168.1.100" ]`

Comment: True. So it's presumably same result, but handling the output a bit better.

Comment: [user]$ perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Answer (score 1):

You say you want

```
[ "192.168.1.100" ]
```

but the code you pass to Perl is

```
[ 192.168.1.100 ]
```

Those are very different.

- `"192.168.1.100"` creates the 13-character string `192.168.1.100`.
- `192.168.1.100` is short for `v192.168.1.100`, and it creates the same 4-character string as `chr(192).chr(168).chr(1).chr(100)`.

One of many ways of writing what you want:

```
my $ip_array = '["192.168.1.100"]';
```